# Do "Shaimot" need to be buried in a certain way or place?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, genizah-storage

Perhaps, I'm asking an overly trivial question. People in my neighborhood sometimes ask me where they can put their *shaimot* (holy writings that require burial.) I also see postings on my community's email list where people ask where they can bring them.

Some shuls have a specific burial site (in one shul, it's on the shul's lawn.) Otherwise, I've seen people throw bags of *shaimot* in the grave when someone is buried.

I understand the "convenience" of having someone else do the work for you. But, technically, couldn't someone just dig a hole in his back yard or lawn and bury the *shaimot* there? Or does it need to be buried in a Jewish cemetery or in front of a shul? Are there any other requirements for where *shaimot* need to be buried?

Are there minimum or maximum pit dimensions?